# Trapezoid angles with bases and legs

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

I wanna know how to find angles of trapezoid (approx) with Bases and legs. Bases are 10cm and 13cm and legs are 6cm and 4cm.
Thanks!!

Comment: One way: extend the legs until they intersect, then calculate the sides of the triangle that formed, then solve the triangle for the base angles.

Answer (score 2):

Label the vertices of the trapezoid $ABCD$ in sequence around the trapezoid so that its bases are $AB=10$ and $CD=13$ and its legs are $AD=6$ and $BC=4.$

Put $P$ on the line between $C$ and $D$ such that $CP = 10.$
Then the quadrilateral $ABCP$ is a parallelogram, and $AP = BC = 4.$

[image]

This problem should be much easier to solve than the original one appeared to be.